# Trouble managing threads on swift

Tags: swift, multithreading, grand-central-dispatch, avaudioplayer, avaudiorecorder

I am writing a program on swift 4, using AV audio kit to do the following:

1.Once the button is pressed, record an audio for 'timeInterval' seconds, and play it immediately once done recording.
2. after it is done playing, go back to step 1, and record an audio... etc.

i want this record and play loop to keep happening, but am having problems due to the thread handling in swift.

instead of staying in the inner while loop, to wait for the recording to finish playing, its subthreading this and continuing with the program, and therefore exiting the outer while loop prematurely.

I want this to happen in a loop, and cant seem to understand how to give the while loop for checking if audio player is done playing, **More priority**

```
@IBAction func buttonPressedDAF(_ sender: UIButton) {

    self.doDAF = true


    print("starting DAF...")


    let filename = getDirectory().appendingPathComponent("\(fileNameString)")

    let settings = [AVFormatIDKey: Int(kAudioFormatAppleLossless),
        AVEncoderAudioQualityKey: AVAudioQuality.max.rawValue,
        AVEncoderBitRateKey: 320000,
        AVNumberOfChannelsKey: 1,
        AVSampleRateKey: 12000.0
    ] as[String: Any]

    while self.finishedPlaying == true {
        do {


            //while true { // keep running in loop till DAF is switched off
            finishedPlaying = false
            audioRecorder =
                try AVAudioRecorder(url: filename, settings: settings)
            audioRecorder.delegate = self

            //audioRecorder.record(forDuration: 2)

            if (audioRecorder.record(forDuration: timeInterval)) // successfull in starting the recording...

            {
                // .now() + number of seconds
                print("started recording for \(timeInterval) seconds...")
                DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + timeInterval) { // waits for 2 seconds for the audio to record, then stops the recorder
                    print("recording succesfull, playing...")
                    self.audioRecorder.stop()
                    self.audioRecorder = nil

                    self.playRecording()

                    while self.audioPlayer.isPlaying == true { // audio is still playing, dont proceed
                        print("audio player is playing...")
                    }


                    print("finished playing audio, proceed to next...")
                    self.finishedPlaying = true

                }
            }

        } catch {
            print("failed...")
        }
    }
}
```

How do i prevent it from subthreading and continuing with the program.

Comment: Instead of polling `isPlaying` and trying to stall in a loop, use `AVAudioPlayerDelegate` to be called back when playing is finished.

Comment: @PhillipMills i'm sorry i don't quite understand.. how do tell it has finished without using a while loop? can you write and example code?

Comment: Look at the documentation for `AVAudioPlayerDelegate`.  If provide the player an object that conforms to that protocol, there's a `audioPlayerDidFinishPlaying` method that gets called.

Comment: I am having the same problem with avaudioplayerdelegate method. after executing self.playRecording, it starts to play it, and then i run my self.avaudioplayerdelegate(self.audioPlayer, successfully: true) to do something when its finished, but inevitably because the recording has not finished, this method doesn't run

Comment: You don't call anything in the delegate.  If you set it up correctly, the player will call it when it's finished playing.  (Do you understand how delegates are meant to be used?)